# Comma-separated query results for use by IN clause in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I wish to return a series of numerical results (i.e. those of a column) and make these comma separated. So the output can be used by the `IN` clause in another query. So I'm looking for *10,20,30,40,50,60* as output when the table data is as follows:

```
ID   Value
1    10
2    20
3    30
4    40
5    50
6    60
```

What is the smartest way to perform this? The following query will use this output string in the following way:

```
select * from Table where Value IN (10,20,30,40,50,60)
```

I've tried creating a variable that takes the output of the select, but I only get one value. i.e.

```
declare @Value_List varchar(799);
select @Value_List = Value from Table select @Value_List;
```

However I only return a single value, let alone a list.

The rationale is that this is a debug script, we have a series of checks that we need to go through manually, so Ideally want to be break down queries into single statements for ease of use and clarity.

Comment: Why do you need to make multiple steps out of this? 1. Run a query. 2.  Assemble the output as a comma-separated string. 3. Pass that output to a different query. @Lamak is absolutely right - stop thinking like JSON and think in sets.

Comment: *think in sets* Well said :)

Comment: Because the results are useful elsewhere and always subject to change. Trying for ease of reading and simplicity rather than elegance.

Answer (score 8):

To do what you want, you'll need to use dynamic SQL. But can you explain better why you want to do it like that?, seems much more simple to just do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
WHERE Value IN (SELECT Value FROM YourTable WHERE ID <= 6)
```

Comment: Because its a pretty complex sql statement that is computed before and really must be separated. Hence I was trying to get SELECT Value FROM YourTable WHERE ID <= 6 into a variable.

Comment: @Navonod Then maybe you can explain your goal with more details so we can give you a set based answer instead of going with dynamic SQL

Comment: Dynamic is fine since these are debug scripts. Not production code, so needs to be easier to read than anything else. @Lamak, I tried the above but I get no results when I do it this way. Does the IN expect query results in a particular format.

Comment: @Navonod To answer that I would need to see the query you are using and the data of your tables. But you don't need a particular format, just making sure that the data types of the columns are compatible

Comment: My Mistake - I messed up a little. It does work, but I'd still like to separate the queries for each of reading.

Comment: *but I'd still like to separate the queries for each of reading*, I don't know what you mean with that. Maybe if you expand your question to explain that requirement we can help you get there, but for now it's impossible

Answer (score 6):

**1)**  Assuming your list of values isn't addressed with a simpler approach like Lamak outlined (i.e. you don't really need a list at all), *here is one way to do it using dynamic SQL*:

```
-- Declare & get the list of values from a query.
DECLARE @values varchar(2000);
SET @values = '';
SELECT @values = @values + CAST(Value AS varchar(5)) + ','
FROM tbl_A; -- hopefully some WHERE criteria here to make this interesting

-- Trim the trailing comma.
SET @values = SUBSTRING(@values, 1, Len(@values) - 1)

---- DEBUG: Confirm the list of values.
--SELECT @values As 'Values'
--/*
--Values
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--10,20,30,40,50,60
--
--(1 row(s) affected)
--*/

-- Dynamically use the list of values in an IN clause.
DECLARE @sql as nvarchar(max);
SET @sql = 'SELECT Value FROM tbl_A WHERE Value IN (' + @values + ')';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
/*
Value
-----------
10
20
30
40
50
60

(6 row(s) affected)
*/
```

[SQLBook.com](http://www.sqlbook.com/SQL/Create-comma-delimited-list-27.aspx) explains this approach in greater depth.

**2)**  *However*, a subquery would be smarter when you could alternatively use one to get the list of values in the `IN` clause - for example:

```
SELECT a.Value
FROM tbl_A a
WHERE
    a.Value IN
        (SELECT b.Value
         FROM tbl_B b
         /* hopefully some WHERE criteria here to make this interesting */);
```

**3)**  *And as a more direct alternative to comma-delimited lists*, consider [Table-Valued Parameters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx).  They can be simple, easy to read, and elegant (per your comment on your question to Lamak) - i.e. smart.

Consider a stored proc that accepts a "list" of IDs as a TVP (i.e. set) of IDs instead:

```
/*
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    IntTableType for int TVPs (i.e. "the TVP")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IntTableType] AS TABLE
(
    Value int
)
GO


/*
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Gets a set of Foos by ID. (i.e. "the stored proc")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspGetFoos]
    @FooIdTable dbo.IntTableType readonly
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT f.ID, f.Column1, f.Column2 -- etcetera
    FROM dbo.Foo f
    WHERE f.ID IN (SELECT fi.Value FROM @FooIdTable);

    ---- or --
    --
    --SELECT f.ID, f.Column1, f.Column2 -- etcetera
    --FROM dbo.Foo f
    --JOIN @FooIdTable fi ON fi.Value = f.ID;
END
GO
```

You could then get the "list" (i.e. set) of IDs in one query and use it in another as you described:

```
DECLARE @fooIds dbo.IntTableType;
INSERT INTO @fooIds (Value)
SELECT IntColumn
FROM dbo.Whatever
WHERE 1 = 1; -- whatever

EXEC dbo.uspGetFoos @FooIdTable = @fooIds;
```

Of course, you could also similarly employ table variables or temp tables for IDs (the former being restricted to a single stored proc, function, or batch, though); but TVPs give you a first-class way to make tabular (i.e. set) data an *input argument*.

Comment: Ok, this answer is just too complete to not upvote it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your delimited values aren't linear like your example, you can create a function that returns a table from a delimited string. I Copied the function from 
[here](http://www.biitb.com/index.php/t-sql-split-function/)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[func_Split] 
    (   
    @DelimitedString    varchar(8000),
    @Delimiter              varchar(100) 
    )
RETURNS @tblArray TABLE
    (
    ElementID   int IDENTITY(1,1),  -- Array index
    Element     varchar(1000)               -- Array element contents
    )
AS
BEGIN

    -- Local Variable Declarations
    -- ---------------------------
    DECLARE @Index      smallint,
                    @Start      smallint,
                    @DelSize    smallint

    SET @DelSize = LEN(@Delimiter)

    -- Loop through source string and add elements to destination table array
    -- ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    WHILE LEN(@DelimitedString) > 0
    BEGIN

        SET @Index = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @DelimitedString)

        IF @Index = 0
            BEGIN

                INSERT INTO
                    @tblArray 
                    (Element)
                VALUES
                    (LTRIM(RTRIM(@DelimitedString)))

                BREAK
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN

                INSERT INTO
                    @tblArray 
                    (Element)
                VALUES
                    (LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@DelimitedString, 1,@Index - 1))))

                SET @Start = @Index + @DelSize
                SET @DelimitedString = SUBSTRING(@DelimitedString, @Start , LEN(@DelimitedString) - @Start + 1)

            END
    END

    RETURN
END
```

And your select would be

```
select * 
from Table 
where Value IN (select Element from func_split('10,20,30,40,50,60', ','))
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/02ed7/1/0)

Answer (score -1):

This should concatenate

```
DECLARE @result VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @result = COALESCE(@result+' ,','')+Value FROM Table

SELECT @result
```

Comment: Your answer should contain an explanation of your code and a description how it solves the problem.